# General question about differentiability of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Conside a complex function $ f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y) $.

It is well known that if $ f $ is $ \mathbb{C} $ - differentiable, then the partial derivatives $ f_x, f_y $ exists, and satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Also, it is well known that if the partial derivatives exists, continuous at a point $ z $, and satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, then the function $ z $ is $ \mathbb{C}$-differentiable at the point $ z $.

I noticed that if the partial derivatives exists and continuous at a point $z$, one can conclude that the function $ f:\mathbb{R}^2\ \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ is differentiable as a real function.

So, the question is : If a function $f(x,y): \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $  is differentiable as a real function, and the partial derivatives satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, can we say that $ f $ is $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable as a complex function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you don't need the continuity of the partial derivatives.

Indeed, if $f$ is differentiable at a point $z_0$, then
$$f(z_0+h)=f(z_0)+\mathrm{df}(z_0)(h) + o(h)$$

Denoting $z_0=x_0+iy_0$, and using Cauchy-Riemann equations, you get
$$f(z_0+h)=f(z_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) \times h + o(h)$$

so $f$ is $\mathbb{C}-$differentiable at $z_0$ (and $f'(z_0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) \times h = \mathrm{df}(z_0)(1)$)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on TheSilverDoe's answer: You can think of complex differentiability as real differentiability with the additional constraint that the total derivative is a rotation-dilation. Complex differentiability in $z_0$ means that there is a number $f'(z_0)$ such that

$$f(z_0+h)=f(z_0)+f'(z_0)\cdot h+o(h).$$

Real differentiability means that there is an $\mathbb R$-linear map $\mathrm Df(z_0):\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ (viewing $\mathbb C$ as an $\mathbb R$ vector space) such that

$$f(z_0+h)=f(z_0)+\mathrm Df(z_0)(h)+o(h).$$

And since multiplication of $h$ by a complex number $f'(z_0)$ is $\mathbb R$-linear, this is really a weaker version of complex differentiability. Complex differentiability requires that $\mathrm Df(z_0)$ can be expressed as multiplication by a complex number - which is just a rotation-dilation. So essentially, complex differentiable functions are those whose differentials do nothing except rotating and dilating, which means that they preserve angles between arbitrary curves (unless $f'(z_0)=0$)!

Comment: Fascinating. When I tried to prove this by myself, I noticed that in order for a function that is $ \mathbb{R} $ - differentiable to be $ \mathbb{C} $-differentiable, the matrix representing the differential should be of the form $ \begin{pmatrix}a & -b\\
b & a
\end{pmatrix} $, But I did not notice that this is actually just a rotation matrix

Comment: That's an excellent observation! Also note that such a matrix can always be expressed in the form $r\begin{pmatrix}\cos\varphi&-\sin\varphi\\ \sin\varphi&\cos\varphi\end{pmatrix}$, where $a=r\cos\varphi,~b=r\sin\varphi$, which corresponds to the polar decomposition of the complex number $a+\mathrm ib$. In this form, it's easy to see that we have a rotation by $\varphi$ and dilation by $r$.